# Remove ShareDaddy meta box from Pages only

Tags: metabox, plugin-jetpack

I'm trying to take away the option to have sharing options on 'pages' (but leave on posts).

So I have a function to make sure the sharing option is always no on pages

```
function page_disable_share($post_id)
{
if ( 'page' != get_post_type() )
    return;

    update_post_meta($post_id, "sharing_disabled", 1);
}
add_action('save_post', 'page_disable_share');
```

But I'd rather not have the meta box there at all, it might confuse the user if they tick it and it always unticks itself.

```
function page_remove_share()
{
    remove_meta_box( 'sharing_meta' , 'page' , 'normal' ); 
}
add_action('admin_menu' , 'page_remove_share');
```

Bu that's not working. Maybe JetPack is getting hooked in after 'admin_menu'? I tried other hooks (http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) but none work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `add_meta_boxes` action with a very low priority, so:

```
function page_remove_share() {
    remove_meta_box( 'sharing_meta' , 'page' , 'advanced' ); 
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'page_remove_share', 99 );
```

I think that should work.

Comment: It had so much potential, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: I had a look how it was hooked in in the plugin itself. The answer is:

remove_meta_box( 'sharing_meta', 'page', 'advanced' );
   
The only difference is that the context is 'advanced'. I can't answer my own question because my rep isn't high enough.

Comment: Ok updated it :)